# Why doesn't child.getType() do what I expect in DocumentApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

So in documentApp, I can run through the children of a document like this:

```
if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
{
  console.log(i, " is a paragraph");}
```

And that works fine.

But if I actually try this:

```
if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH)
{
  console.log(i, " is a paragraph");
} else {
console.log(i, p.getType());
```

I get a giant gibberish structure for the p.getType(), rather than just a type.

How do I get all the types in the document without the structure? I don't want to have to make an elaborate case tree.

--- Result I get --

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. 37 { toString: [Function: toString],
  name: [Function: toString],
  toJSON: [Function: toString],
  ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
  compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
  AUTOGENERATED_REGION: 
   { toString: [Function: toString],
     name: [Function: toString],
     toJSON: [Function: toString],
     ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
     compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
     AUTOGENERATED_REGION: [Circular],
     BODY_SECTION: 
      { toString: [Function: toString],
        name: [Function: toString],
        toJSON: [Function: toString],
        ordinal: [Function: ordinal],
        compareTo: [Function: compareTo],
        AUTOGENERATED_REGION: [Circular],
        BODY_SECTION: [Circular],
        COMMENT_SECTION: [Object],
        DOCUMENT: [Object],
        EQUATION: [Object],
        EQUATION_FUNCTION: [Object],
        EQUATION_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_SEPARATOR: [Object],
        EQUATION_SYMBOL: [Object],
        FOOTER_SECTION: [Object],
        FOOTNOTE: [Object],
        FOOTNOTE_SECTION: [Object],
        HEADER_SECTION: [Object],
        HORIZONTAL_RULE: [Object],
        INLINE_DRAWING: [Object],
        INLINE_IMAGE: [Object],
        LIST_ITEM: [Circular],
        PAGE_BREAK: [Object],
```

Comment: could you show the gibberish structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `getType()` on an child of type `Element` you get back an instance of `ElementType`.

`ElementType` is an enumerated type and will resolve to a string under certain circumstances. For example, when you use it in the first `console.log()` it's concatenated to the string `" is a paragraph"`. With string concatenation, the `toString()` method is automatically invoked on the `ElementType` instance and the resulting string `paragraph` is pre-pended.

With the second call to `console.log()` things can get weird now that we're defaulting to the V8 runtime. [According to the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Parameters):

> *Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console.*

So I assume that the gibberish you're seeing is the result of the `console.log()` attempting to resolve its object parameters but it doesn't have any context to infer string concatenation so you end up with a concatenation of object references (since `toString()` invocations aren't called).

Something else you'll want to keep in mind. Enumerated types are basically singletons, so that each instance of an enumerated type is a universally unique object (for example, there is only one instance of `DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH` that exists). So its preferable to test for object equality with the `===` operator, instead of using `==`.

Comment: i is the number in the child list not the object itself, but I'll see if I can figure out something from what you said.

Comment: RESULT!: p.getType().toString() gets me what I wanted!